Enable syntax highlighting
For questions like this one which have answers given in code, it would be nice if the site had syntax highlighting available.  At the very least, being able to highlight core SO lanaguages such as python would be nice, but support for NASM and other languages common in the reverse engineering field would also be helpful.  Is there a known process for enabling syntax highlighting?

@CamilStaps that question is specifically about specifying the language for the (already enabled) highlighter. It appears that we don't have syntax highlighting at all on RE.SE.

+1 Syntax Highlighting would be a welcome addition but why not accept all languages like on SO? Just python or NASM is very limited.

@Remko I was attempting to make a distinction between what I know is already supported vs a language that there doesn't seem to be support of for any of the SO sites.  I clarified the question to make the distinction.

Followup discussion: How about finally enabling syntax highlighting for RE.SE? – and request: Please enable syntax highlighting for RE.SE

Yes please. I fail to see how better annotation tools could make the site worse other than adding to the loading time a bit. In my opinion when it comes to reverse engineering, annotation and presentation is very important.

What do we need to do to make this happen? Is this something the mods need to bring up to SE higher ups?

I'd like to revisit this topic. This meta post confirms that syntax highlighting still isn't enabled on this site. Can someone enable it? A question I recently answered is a good example of why it would be really useful.

admittedly I've never missed it. Could you come up with the other nine examples required to request this officially? If you edit your answer accordingly (and ping me or other mods in a comment) we could see if it's possible and point the respective SE staffers to your edited answer. The cited meta post in  its only answer says: post a request on the site's per-site meta and link to some (10 or so) posts where highlighting would be helpful ...

It's now enabled, btw.

Ha, I meant to respond to this back in 2020 and completely forgot about it. Good to see my forgetfulness didn't prevent it from getting enabled anyway; thanks for following up.

The code highlighting for syntax does exist as noted in some of the comments, but it isn't enabled here yet for whatever reason.  
For less likely to be available syntax highlighting (insert a language it doesn't work on), I simply link to pastebin and select the appropriate language there.
